# How to capture user's name and phone number when they click mailto?

Tags: javascript, android, mobile

How am I able to capture mobile user's name and phone when they click on mailto? I'm able to have it pre-filled or get only the email, but how can I pre-fill user name and phone?

For example, can we have some javascript that can grab the mobile user's name and phone number connected to the phone and then pre-populate this information when they click mailto?

Comment: read this, we have nothing to go by here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @JordanHendrix actually we do, the user is simply asking how to get the username and phone number from the html mailto functionality

Comment: @prexcel2215 Please add more details and let us know what you have already tried.